# How to stretch columns *after* they are layed out on multiple rows in CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to replicate this flex-box with grids:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main > article{
    flex:1 1 400px;
}
```

For example, if the row track is 900px, flex will put two articles per line (given the flex-basis of 400px) and it will grow each of them to 450px later.

Essentially my ideal item width is 400px, which I am willing to stretch as much as possible but without stealing space from other flex items.

Is there a way to do something like this with grids?

Thank you.

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    width:90px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border:2px blue solid;
}

main > article{
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex:1 1 40px;
    border:2px red solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>A</article>
  <article>B</article>
  <article>C</article>
  <article>D</article>
  <article>E</article>
</main>
```

Comment: No...that's not the way CSS-Grid works. Elements can't expand automatically without a defined width.

Comment: that's a bummer. not even with a combination of minmax() min-width/max-width/width?

Comment: @WesAtWork Do you know the number of columns in advance?

Comment: No, it has to be dynamic, like flex with flex-wrap. As many items as possible on each row (I am the OP)